# View most popular keywords used in conjunction with X

Tags: search, google-search, keyword

I know how to use [Google trends](http://www.google.com/trends/explore) to explore the popularity of keywords over time or resolved by the geographical region. I would however also be interested in finding out what other keywords are commonly used in conjunction with a said keyword.

Is there any way to do this?